# I am developing login screen. Doing styling with postCSS. while importing my style in Login.js giving below error mentioned in screenshot

Tags: postcss

[image]

I am not able to import style

import styles from "./Login.css";

Comment: Can you show the whole CSS file?

Comment: ```
.loginContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

```

Comment: @RenatoDamas please find snippet below

Answer (score 0):

```
This is Login.css

            .loginContainer {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          flex: 1;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          background-color: red;
        }


    This is This is Login.js

    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";


    import styles from "./Login.css";

    export default class Login extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      render() {
        return <div className={styles.loginContainer} />;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried fixing the indentation in the Login.css file?